# Сглаживание контуров изображения

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, графика, обработка-изображений, gdi

Необходимо оставить на фотографии небольшое количество цветов.
Получилось реализовать с помощью перевода изображения в режим индексных цветов.

Теперь стоит задача сгладить края (убрать шум).

Выделенное желтым (где есть множество мелких деталей) сделать черным.
Выделенное красным сделать бежевым и белым.

[image: исходное]

Подумываю о векторизации растра.
В иллюстраторе получилось сделать лучше, но все еще не идеально (выделил элементы от которых так же нужно избавится).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какими алгоритмами возможно реализовать подобное?
Какие библиотеки есть для векторизации растровых изображении?